# How to get count of opportunities related with an account in SOQL query?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql

I want the count of opportunities that an account is related with. I tried the following SOQL query
`Select Name,(Select Count(Id) from Opportunities) from account` but it is given following error `only root queries support aggregate expressions`

Comment: can you try the below SOQL query `SELECT count(id), AccountId FROM Opportunity GROUP BY AccountId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use aggregate expressions in root Queries. for getting the count if opportunities on each account you have to use the below SOQL query.

```
SELECT count(id), AccountId FROM Opportunity GROUP BY AccountId
```

or you can follow the below approach.

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name,(SELECT id FROM opportunities) FROM Account];

for (Account acc : accounts) {
     System.debug('Count of Opportunities is ' + acc.Opportunities.size());
}
```

Comment: N.B. If an account has more than 2,000 opportunities, the for loop can fail. Not a problem for most people, but is a consideration if you're not sure if there's a lot of records.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for pointing out it